# Time Complexity of multi loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I know that:

```
for(i;i<n;i++){
   for(j;j<n;j++){
      //code
   }
}
```

is O(n^2)

but something like:

```
do{
    printf("Insert i:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    do{
        printf("Insert n:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }while(n<0);
    do{
        printf("Insert z:");
        scanf("%d",&z);
    }while(z<0);
}while(i<0);
```

Until the user enters a correct value, the internal cycles continue to iterate. It could be O(n^3)?

Comment: What is code inside `while(//code)`?

Comment: If the loops are entirely dependent on user input then I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about time complexity... There is no "n" to depend on...

Comment: @sameerkn I have edited the code to be more clear

Comment: All it can be said is the complexity is atleast 1 `Ω(1)`.

Comment: I think usually the runtime complexity would not be analyzed in terms of user interarction as described above. Note that, depending on the input, each loop can potentially run forver, which makes an analysis difficult. Usually the runtime complexity is estimated for algorithms which terminate for every input or at least the set of inputs is restricted to instances for which the algorithm terminates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, an estimate could be given as follows. Let `m` be the minimum of all numbers entered. If

```
m < 0
```

holds, the algorithm does not terminate, as one of the loops must run forver. If

```
m >= 0
```

holds, the algorithm has a runtime complexity of

```
O(1)
```

as each loop takes only one iteration.